# Remote Git Repository in document root

Tags: git, remote-server, git-push

Im trying to use git for my website. The website is on our webserver.

```
mkdir /home/website/public_html
cd /home/website/public_html
git --bare init
```

Then I go to the local machine and change into the directory where I have my files

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@server.com:/home/website/public_html
git push origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/git/.ssh/id_rsa':
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 460 bytes, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@server.com:/home/website/public_html
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

But now when I got to my back to my server:

```
ls /home/website/public_html
branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs
```

Where are my files I pushed to the server? Am I going about this the wrong way? (the only thing in the local folder I pushed from was a readme)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created a bare repository on the server. Bare repositories do not have a working area.

I assume you are trying to use Git for website publishing? See [this link](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) for one option. In short:

- You create 2 repositories on the server. One is a bare repository, just like the one you have already created, but it's outside of the public_html directory
- Other is a normal repository inside the public_html directory
- You create a post-receive hook that updates the repository inside the public_html directory whenever you push to the bare repository

Answer (score 0):

You have to clone your repository that you created with git --bare init. See [git clone](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html).
For example :

1) create a repository with git --bare init in a folder on your server

2) clone that repository somewhere where you want to work with like public_html

3) after you add something new in your clone folder, use:

```
git add .
git commit -a -m" message for commit "
git push origin master
```

And to get the code from your repository use:

```
git pull origin master
```

and that will merge the code from repository with your local branch

Comment: did you mean `git push origin master` and `git pull origin master`?