# Can't access files in Git remote repo

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have an app on GitHub.  I pull this down to my laptop, edit the files, and push back to GitHub, no problem.

Now, I want to deploy this app to my server.  So, I SSH into my server and I create a git repo:

```
ssh git@example.com
mkdir my_project.git
cd my_project.git
git init --bare
```

Then, from my laptop, I run this:

```
git remote add myserver git@example.com:my_project.git
git push -u myserver master
```

But, then when I SSH back to the remote server, I don't see any files and I cannot seem to check them out (if I try to checkout, I get this: "fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree")

Please help, I would like to be able to SSH back into my server and run my app (node server.js) just like I do locally.

Thanks!

Comment: *bare* repos have no working copy, ergo no files. there's a lot of articles on abusing git for deployment, so google should be real helpful here

Comment: This is covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160941/remote-git-repository-in-document-root/16161464#16161464

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bare repository does not contain a working directory.  But you need a bare repository to push to.

One solution is to create a second repository on the server that is not bare.  The second repository could pull from the bare repository (possibly automated in a cronjob.)  You could run your app from this second repository.